# Vcpkg "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: c++, windows-10, command-line-interface, vcpkg

Couples of days ago Vcpkg began to shut down immediately on build stage:

[Shutting down after build starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7zQZ.png)

After several re installations I've noticed that line:

["The system cannot find the path specified"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwazS.png)

Same line I've found in virtual environment(vcpkg env):

[In env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO96Q.png)

What does that mean? Path to Vcpkg already placed in `$env:Path` variable.
In addition, here's output of installing in debug mode:

[Debug mode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXurS.png)

Comment: ***the system cannot find the path specified*** This likely means you are in the wrong folder when you typed that. I don't believe you give us enough information to help. Not only that it's better that you copy and paste the output as text instead of pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in variable `Autorun`. I've opened registry.exe and navigated to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`. There was some junk with miniconda bat-file. So, I've just clear the value and problem disappeared.